# How to create the hierarchical menu structure for a particular role using LINQ to XML in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Menu>
  <Role Id="Admin">
    <ParentItems>
      <ParentItem Id="1" DisplayText="Home" Url="" >
      </ParentItem>
      <ParentItem Id="2" DisplayText="Proposal" Url="">
        <ChildItems>
          <ChildItem Id="1" DisplayText="Create" Url=""/>
          <ChildItem Id="2" DisplayText="Search" Url=""/>
        </ChildItems>
      </ParentItem>
    </ParentItems>
  </Role>
  <Role Id="User">
    <ParentItems>
      <ParentItem Id="1" DisplayText="Home" Url="" />
      <ParentItem Id="2" DisplayText="Proposal" Url="">
        <ChildItems>
          <ChildItem Id="1" DisplayText="Create" Url=""/>
          <ChildItem Id="2" DisplayText="Search" Url=""/>
        </ChildItems>
      </ParentItem>
      <ParentItem Id="3" DisplayText="Profile" Url="">
        <ChildItems>
          <ChildItem Id="1" DisplayText="Extended Profile" Url=""/>
        </ChildItems>
      </ParentItem>
    </ParentItems>
  </Role>
</Menu>

public class ChildMenuVm
{
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
public class ParentMenuVm
{
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public IList<ChildMenuVm> ChildMenuVms{ get; set; }

    public ParentMenuVm()
    {
        ChildMenuVms= new List<ChildMenuVm>();
    }
}
public class MenuViewModel
{
    public List<ParentMenuVm> MenuList { get; set; }

    public MenuViewModel()
    {
        MenuList = new List<ParentMenuVm>();
    }
}
```

function for linq query

```
menuVm.MenuList = (from items in xElement.Elements("Role")
                          where items.Attribute("Id").Value == role
                          from parent in items.Elements("ParentItems")
                          select new ParentMenuVm()
                          {
                              MenuId = parent.Element("ParentItem").Attribute("Id").Value.ToString(),
                              DisplayText = parent.Element("ParentItem").Attribute("DisplayText").Value.ToString(),
                              Url = parent.Element("ParentItem").Attribute("Url").Value.ToString(),
                              ChildMenuVms = (from child in items.Elements("ChildItems")
                                              select new ChildMenuVm()
                                              {
                                                  MenuId = child.Element("ChildItem").Attribute("Id").Value.ToString(),
                                                  DisplayText = child.Element("ChildItem").Attribute("DisplayText").Value.ToString(),
                                                  Url = child.Element("ChildItem").Attribute("Url").Value.ToString(),
                                              }).ToList()
                          }
                           ).ToList();
```

The above query just returns the first parent item that too not the child items. Also other parent are not loaded.

Comment: I want to get a hierarchical menu structure out of that xml and the classes provided. Earlier I was able to load only the first parent item but that also didn't have any child items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see few issues with your code, first I am not sure what is `xElement` what you already have in that. Second, you are getting only first person because you are querying `items.Elements("ParentItems")` and I see just `ParentItems` node in your XML. Third problem is here: `items.Elements("ChildItems")` in your query `items` represents elements of `Role` but it does not directly contain any `ChildItems` rather it is present inside `ParentItem`. Also you are always querying with `Element` and then `Element` it may lead to `Null Reference Exception` if any element in your XML is missing. I will rather do it like this:-

```
menuVm.MenuList = (from role in xdoc.Root.Elements("Role")
                   where (string)role.Attribute("Id") == role
                   from parentItems in role.Element("ParentItems").Elements("ParentItem")
                   let ChildItems = parentItems.Descendants("ChildItem")
                   select new ParentMenuVm
                       {
                          MenuId = (string)parentItems.Attribute("Id"),
                          DisplayText = (string)parentItems.Attribute("DisplayText"),
                          Url = (string)parentItems.Attribute("Url"),
                          ChildMenuVms = (from child in ChildItems
                                   select new ChildMenuVm 
                                    {
                                      MenuId = (string)child.Attribute("Id"),
                                      DisplayText = (string)child.Attribute("DisplayText"),
                                      Url = (string)child.Attribute("Url")
                                    }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

Here `xdoc` is XDocuemnt object:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"YourXMlFilePath");
```

Comment: @SumitSaha - You're Welcome:) You can accept the answer if that helped you. Check how - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work